# C++ invalid conversion int* to int

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment that asks to create a few functions to read data, calculate scores, and output data, respectively.

I feel like I'm very close to having this complete, but keep running into the following errors:

> 66 [Error] invalid conversion from `int (*)(studentType*, int)` to `int`  [-fpermissive]
>
> 30 [Error]   initializing argument 3 of `void printResults(std::ofstream&, studentType*, int, int)` [-fpermissive]

I searched through stackoverflow and other forums but can't quite get to the bottom of it. Does anyone know what in my code might be causing these errors?

I also have a sneaking suspicion that the way I'm passing values isn't totally spot on. I know that's an open-ended question, but any feedback would be appreciated.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <iomanip>
    
    using namespace std;
    
    //sets limit for students
    const int max_students = 20;
    
    //student info struct
    struct studentType
    {
        string firstName;
        string lastName;
        int score;
        char grade;
    };
    
    //function declarations
    void dataInput(ifstream& inFile, studentType slist[], int listSize);
    void calcGrade(studentType sList[], int listSize);
    void printResults(ofstream& outFile, studentType sList[], int highScore, int listSize);
    int highScore(studentType sList[], int listSize);
    
    int main()
    {
        
        ifstream inFile;
        ofstream outFile;
        int listSize = max_students;
        studentType sList[max_students];
        
        //checks for input file
        inFile.open("scores.txt");
        
            if (!inFile)
            {
                cout << "No input file detected.. please try again." << endl;
                
                return 0;   
            }
        
        //checks for output file    
        outFile.open("results.txt");
            
            if (!outFile)
            {
                cout << "Cannot locate output file.. please try again" << endl;
                
                return 0;   
            }
        
        //calls functions
        dataInput(inFile, sList, listSize);
        
        calcGrade(sList, listSize);
        
        printResults(outFile, sList, highScore, listSize);
        
        return 0;
        
    }
    
    //function to collect names and scores from each student
    void dataInput(ifstream& inFile, studentType sList[], int listSize)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            
            inFile >> sList[i].firstName >> sList[i].lastName >> sList[i].score;
                
        }
        
    }
    
    //calculates grades based on input scores
    void calcGrade(studentType sList[], int score, int listSize)
    {
        
        for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            if (score >= 90)
                sList[i].score = 'A';
            else if (score >= 80)
                sList[i].score = 'B';
            else if (score >= 70)
                sList[i].score = 'C';
            else if (score >= 60)
                sList[i].score = 'D';
            else 
                sList[i].score = 'F';
            
        }
        
    }
    
    //calculates highest score(s)
    int highScore(studentType sList[], int listSize)
    {
        
        int i = 0;
        
        int highScore = sList[i].score;
        
        for(i; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            if(sList[i].score > highScore)
            {
                highScore = sList[i].score;
            }
            
        }
        
        
        return highScore;
    }
    
    //prints results into output file
    void printResults(ofstream& outFile, studentType sList[], int highScore, int listSize)
    {
        
        int topScore = highScore;
        int i = 0;
        
        //header
        outFile << setw(10) << "Name " << setw(10) << "Score " << setw(10) << "Grade " << endl;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
        {
            //content
            outFile << left << setw(25) << sList[i].lastName << ", " << sList[i].firstName <<
            right << " " << setw(5) << sList[i].score << setw(5) << " " << sList[i].grade << endl;
            
            outFile << " " << endl;
            
            outFile << "Highest test score: " << topScore << endl;
            
            outFile << "Students with the highest score: " << endl;
            
            for(int i = 0; i < listSize; i++)
            {
                if (sList[i].score == topScore)
                {
                    outFile << sList[i].lastName << ", " << sList[i].firstName << endl;
                }
                
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Do you really think it's helpful to post up all the code?!

Comment: @Bathsheba  i'm new to this site. i don't recall seeing not to do that in the recommendations, but thanks for being snarky.

Comment: i thought it would be helpful to establish context, but i know now not to.

Comment: @elpretentio: Sorry if you feel insulted; our community (esp. C++) tends to get pretty jaded. Please refer to the description of a [mcve] to help us help you.

Comment: If i can i would recommend to use `std::vector<studentType> sList` and use STL algorithms, which you can avoid such unreadable loops.

Comment: @Radek ok, i will look into that, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
int main()
    ...
    printResults(outFile, sList, highScore, listSize);
    return 0;
}
```

The 3rd argument you put `highScore` but it is a function you declared !!! And it should be an `int` number.

Answer (score 1):

two main problems:

1. you defined `void calcGrade(studentType sList[], int listSize);` but then implemented it as `void calcGrade(studentType sList[], int score, int listSize)`
2. in main you're using variable `highScore` which is not defined, only function with such name is defined, this is why you're getting strange error that pointer to function cannot be converted to int